# Screen went black after changing graphics to nvidia?

Tags: 14.04

I was trying to improve the performance so I installed nvidia. But then when i logged out the screen just got all black. Whenever i restart I see ubuntu dots...screen goes black... drum plays and thats it complete dark!! I can't even login. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Not a permanent solution, but try pressing `Ctrl+alt+f3` and then switching back using `ctrl+alt+f7` (could be f1/f2 depending on your setup). If that doesn't work, try closing the screen, letting the machine sleep and opening it again.

Comment: I tried.. saw few commands processing but again screen went off

Comment: It was `scanning btrfs file systems`